# How can I programmatically activate an OLE control via COM interfaces?

Tags: c, windows, com, ole

I have an application which embeds a button control via ActiveX. The button was provided by a third party, and it implements a whole range of ActiveX interfaces (among which is [`IOleInPlaceObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). I do have an reference to the [`IUnknown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680509%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) implementation of the button.

The problem I'm facing is that the [`IOleWindow::GetWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687282%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function provided by the object always returns an error; the error code is 0x80004005 which is apparently a [common HRESULT value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) meaning `E_FAIL`. Not too descriptive.

For what it's worth, the object also exposes a `hWnd` property via it's [`IDispatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221608.aspx) implementation; querying it succeeds, but the value of the property is always zero.

A bit of googling suggested that I may need to 'activate' the OLE object before the `hWnd` property yields a useful value. Does anybody know how to do this, is there a dedicated COM interface for activating OLE objects?

Interestingly, the button *does* seem to have a window handle, as is visible in [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

**UPDATE:** I just found [`IQuickActivate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is implemented by the button control I'm dealing with, and which can be used to 'quickly' (ahem...) activate an item. However, filling the [`QACONTAINER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure seems to be quite a pain, so I'll rather not do that right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that sending the `OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE` verb using the `IOleClientSite::DoVerb` function helped, like this:

```
IOleInPlaceObjectPtr oleInPlaceObj;
CheckAndThrow( unk->QueryInterface( &oleInPlaceObj ) ) );

HWND hwnd;
CheckAndThrow( oleInPlaceObj->GetWindow( &hwnd ) );

IOleObjectPtr oleObj;
if ( SUCCEEDED( unk->QueryInterface( &oleObj ) ) ) {
    IOleClientSitePtr clientSite;
    if ( SUCCEEDED( oleObj->GetClientSite( &clientSite ) ) ) {
        hr = oleObj->DoVerb( OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE,
                             NULL,
                             clientSite,
                             0,
                             NULL,
                             NULL );
        if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
            if ( SUCCEEDED( oleInPlaceObj->GetWindow( &hwnd ) ) ) {
                return hwnd;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`unk` is an `IUnknownPtr` for which I'm trying to get the `HWND`. The `CheckAndThrow` function is a helper macro which yields an exception in case the given return code indicates a failure.

Answer (score 0):

Naturally button has a valid `HWND`, othrewise it wouldn't be a button/window.
You may get the `HWND` of any control by using `GetDlgItem` or similar.

I'm not certain either about how to activate the object *programmatically*. I'd try the following:

- Call `ReactivateAndUndo`. According to doc this may do what you need IMHO.
- If you have the control `HWND` (and you definitely may obtain it if it exists) - it's possible to simulate user mouse input